# Add TabBArController to the UIView

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Adding tab bar controller to the `UIView` by `[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view]`;
is not loaded the content view controllers view, while selecting the tab bar items it crashed. When set the tab bar controller to the root view controller its working fine. How to set tab bar controller into UIView so that I can set another view for some other purpose like iAd?

Comment: Have you added the tabbar controller as a child view controller by using method like addChildViewController: & didMoveToViewController? or just used addSubView?

Answer (score 0):

You just create one tabbar controller in app delegate but don't add it to window, and in view controller you have just add these:

```
  gObjAppDelegate.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  gObjAppDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2];
 [gObjAppDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:gObjAppDelegate.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

gObjAppDelegate is **shared singleton instance** of app delegate.This way it worked for me.